Analytics-Report-Order Woocommerce Orders Attribution
File -> analytics-report-orders.js - The only way I found to overwrite this page (Analytics/Orders)
I'm trying to show a sum of all orders attributions, at first I got from the Rows - but it's limited to the items per page (25 in this case).
So it returns me 25 orders attribution in getSummary(e) function. And I'm getting the attributions on getRowsContent()
The main issue now is the rendering, at the same time it reads and add the values on the list, it tries to write (which doesn't work).
If  I console.log in the GetRowsContent, inside the return, it gives me the list updated, but the problem is rendering the current data at same time.
The code:
constructor (){... , this.attributionCounts= {};this.processedOrderIds = new Set();}
getRowsContent(e) {

                        const { query: t } = this.props,
                            o = (0, d.getPersistedQuery)(t),
                            c = (0, b.O3)("dateFormat", _.defaultTableDateFormat),
                            { render: a, getCurrencyConfig: s } = this.context;
this.attributionCounts = {};
                        this.processedOrderIds = new Set();

                        for (const order of e.slice(0, t.per_page)) {
                            const {
                                order_id: p,
                                net_total: m,
                                extended_info: v = {}
                            } = order,
                                { attribution } = v;

                            if (attribution && attribution.origin && !this.processedOrderIds.has(p)) {
                                const origin = attribution.origin;
                                if (!this.attributionCounts[origin]) {
                                    this.attributionCounts[origin] = { count: 0, total: 0 };
                                }
                                this.attributionCounts[origin].count += 1;
                                this.attributionCounts[origin].total += m;
                                this.processedOrderIds.add(p);
                            }
                        }

                        return (0, m.map)(e, (e) => {
                            const {
                                currency: t,
                                date: n,
                                net_total: m,
                                num_items_sold: _,
                                order_id: p,
                                order_number: w,
                                parent_id: h,
                                status: f,
                                customer_type: y,
                            } = e,
                                v = e.extended_info || {},
                                { coupons: g, customer: S, products: C } = v,
                                x = C.sort((e, t) => t.quantity - e.quantity).map((e) => ({
                                    label: e.name,
                                    quantity: e.quantity,
                                    href: (0, d.getNewPath)(o, "/analytics/products", {
                                        filter: "single_product",
                                        products: e.id,
                                    }),
                                })),
                                k = g.map((e) => ({
                                    label: e.code,
                                    href: (0, d.getNewPath)(o, "/analytics/coupons", {
                                        filter: "single_coupon",
                                        coupons: e.id,
                                    }),
                                }));
                            
                            return [...];

                            var E;
                        });
                    }
getSummary(e) {
                        const {
                            orders_count: t = 0,
                            total_customers: o = 0,
                            products: r = 0,
                            num_items_sold: c = 0,
                            coupons_count: a = 0,
                            net_revenue: s = 0,
                            attribution = this.attributionCounts
                        } = e,

                            { formatAmount: n, getCurrencyConfig: m } = this.context,
                            i = m();
                        const attributionSummary = Object.keys(this.attributionCounts).map(origin => {
                            const { count, total } = this.attributionCounts[origin];
                            return {
                                label: `R$ ${total.toFixed(2)}`,
                                value: `${origin} (${count})`,
                            };
                        });


                        const summary = [consts on "e"];
                        return [...summary, ...attributionSummary];
                    }
render() {
                        const { query: e, filters: t, advancedFilters: o } = this.props;
                        return (0, r.createElement)(w.Z, {
                            endpoint: "orders",
                            getHeadersContent: this.getHeadersContent,
                            getRowsContent: this.getRowsContent,
                            getSummary: this.getSummary,
                            summaryFields: [
                                "orders_count",
                                "total_customers",
                                "products",
                                "num_items_sold",
                                "coupons_count",
                                "net_revenue",
                                
                            ],
                            query: e,
                            tableQuery: { extended_info: !0 },
                            title: (0, l.__)("Orders", "woocommerce"),
                            columnPrefsKey: "orders_report_columns",
                            filters: t,
                            advancedFilters: o,
                        });
                    }


Is the server is accessible to add a code snippet to bypass the rest API limit of 25?

Actually not, I managed to got what I need, but the current render is not working properly. It adds to the list(object), but at same time it tries to write, which obviously appears a empty list. Now I'm trying to correct this error (I'll edit the post with new code)
